# remove db login window in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

i have a windows application in .net 2005 upgraded to .net 2012. the old version is running fine on a Win2003 Server. db is 2005 express on Win2003 Server.
On my machine (Win7 - SQL Express 2005) the application is running fine with .net 2012. But on A Win2016 Server, all crystal reports display db login window and db name cant be seen although it has been provided. i have installed express 2012 on win2016 server for driver.

Here is my code :

```
MyReport reportDelivery = new MyReport ();
                           reportDelivery.DataSourceConnections[0].SetConnection(Globals.DB_Loc,Globals.DBName , Globals.ReadUser_Name, Globals.ReadPassWord);
```

all parameters have values and they are being used in other places.
report is running fine with above method in the old version ?

Where is the mistake ?

Comment: i have build a simple app in vs 2012 with a new report and deployed it. it runs fine in both development and production machines. 

i included a report from above application (upgraded) and give same database login window (without database name).

Thus , i guess the problem in converting reports to new version.

Comment: i opened some reports and re saved them. i got a msg asking if i want to save with new format, i clicked yes. Again same window is coming once i call a report. further more, some reports give a msg "database login failed" although i'm getting entire report in development machine.

Any Idea ?